# Create new colums based on times of rows

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe made up of datetime (Datetime), sensor_id (int), value (float)
The sensor ids are distinct columns like
below where I show just two sensor ids

```
    ts                   620611      620613    
    2022-02-08 00:00:00  0.100098     0.0          
    2022-02-08 01:00:00  0.000000     0.0             
    2022-02-08 01:30:00  0.000000     0.0                   
    2022-02-08 02:00:00  0.000000     0.0
```

What I would like todo is to check the ts (datetime) value is between certain hours lets say 8:00 -> 20:00 (daylight hours) or outside those house (non daylight_hours).

I then want to take a mean average of the values over the two time ranges for every sensor_id.
Finally I would like to add these results as new extra columns.

For example to make it clearer I would like the final dataframe to be like below with one row showing the mean averages.

```
ts, 620611, 620613, 620611_daylight_hours, 620611_non_daylight_hours,
620613_daylight_hours, 620613_non_daylight_hours
```

How can I accomplish that ?

I did think about perhaps looping through the original columns and doing something like

pandas_df[sensor_id + '_daylight'] = (pandas_df['ts'].dt.hour > 8 & ts.dt.hour <= 20)
but not sure how to make that put values in that col if the test succeeds and None if it does't.

If I could do that I could then do the averaging on the columns ignoring the Nones ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this would be a very denormalized database structure. You want to add a column that contains the average of the values of another column across all records within a given time range? So ... if you have 1,000 sensor readings during "daytime", then each one of those 1000 records will contain the same value for the average? You will repeat that same value over and over again in every record? That's a lot of redundant data. Are you going to update this every time you get a new reading? So reading #1 you update 1 record, reading #2 you update #1 and #2, etc, so reading #1000 you update 1000 records? Why?

It would probably also be cleaner to have a separate record for each sensor rather than combine them all into one record. But maybe there are performance or procedural reasons for one record.

I think what you really want is another table with (timeframe, sensor ID, average), where "timeframe" is some code for day versus night, like 1=day and 2=night or whatever.

I'm not familiar with "panda" so I don't know what functions are available to you. But you'd want to run a query equivalent to "select avg(620611) where hour(ts)>=8 and hour(ts)<20, then insert these into the new table.

I'll gladly yield to someone with knowledge of "panda" who can speak more specifically to the available commands.

Comment: This is for a display purposes and will only run one a days against the last seven days of values so performance doesn't need to be great.
Made be its easier if the sensor_id is replaced by what they are
The final dataframe I want is like

              IncomingElec (daylight hours),  IncomingElec (night hours),   Export (daylight hours),    Export (night hours)
House1               2.3                   ,               1,                         2,                       0